# "unrecognized selector sent to instance" with a class inheriting from NSAttributedString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a class that inherits from `NSAttributedString` like this:

Text.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Text : NSAttributedString

-(id) initWithString:(NSString*) text andFont:(NSFont*)font andLineHeight:(float) lineHeight andLetterSpacing:(float) letterSpacing;

@end
```

Text.m:

```
#import "Text.h"

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@implementation Text

-(id) initWithString:(NSString*) text andFont:(NSFont*)font andLineHeight:(float) lineHeight andLetterSpacing:(float) letterSpacing
{
    NSMutableParagraphStyle* paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    [paragraphStyle setParagraphStyle: [NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle]];
    paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = lineHeight;
    NSDictionary* attributes =
    @{
        NSFontAttributeName: font,
        NSKernAttributeName: @(letterSpacing),
        NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle
    };
    self = [super initWithString:text attributes:attributes];
    return self;
}

@end
```

When I instantiate the class like this:

```
[[Text alloc] initWithString:@"Test" andFont:welcomeLabelFont andLineHeight:52 andLetterSpacing:0.0f]];
```

I get the following exception:

```
2017-07-17 17:21:15.771610+0300 Test[41403:10128169] -[Text initWithString:attributes:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000000f70
```

The selector is available in the base class, event ctrl clicking it jumps to the `NSAttributedText` class. Can anyone point what am I doing wrong? The arguments are not nil pointers and the call seems legitimate. The only thing that seems weird is that the error has the class name `Text` not `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: NSAttributedString is a class cluster, and may not be subclassed.  What are you hoping to achieve in the subclass?  It may be approximated with an extension, or possibly avoided altogether.

Comment: @danh I wanted to make a class that internally hides the construction of the attribute dictionary. Coming from a c++ world it seemed fine, but now I regret it. What marks the class as non derivable? Why am I allowed to inherit from it then?

Comment: See here about clusters.  (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassCluster.html).  You can do what you're aiming for with an extension.  I'll write up something in Xcode to confirm and post it here in a few.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instad of a subclass, use an extension.  Like this

```
// in NSAttributedString+init.h
//
@interface NSAttributedString (Init)

-(instancetype) initWithString:(NSString*) text andFont:(NSFont*)font andLineHeight:(float) lineHeight andLetterSpacing:(float) letterSpacing;

@end
```

And then,  `

```
// in NSAttributedString+init.m
//
#import "NSAttributedString+init.h"

@implementation NSAttributedString (Init)

-(instancetype) initWithString:(NSString*) text andFont:(NSFont*)font andLineHeight:(float) lineHeight andLetterSpacing:(float) letterSpacing {
    // ...
}
```

Import that extension header wherever you want to use your convenience initializer.